# asp.net mvc strongly-typed redirect with modelbinded input parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, query-string, strong-typing

I have a bunch of action methods inside my controller each with its own model binded as input parameter es.:

```
[HttpGet]
public MyActionMethod(MyCustomModel data){
...
}

...

public class MyCustomModel{
    public int total {get;set;}
    public string description {get;set;}
}
```

Now if I try to call the method passing the right set of querystring parameters to compose MyCustomModel everything works as expected.
If I redirect to the action method from another actionmethod using:

```
RedirectToAction("MyActionMethod", new { total=10, description="test"});
```

It also works as expected.

The problem is that I would like to achive some kind of strongly typed redirect something like:

```
RedirectToAction(c => c.MyActionMethod, new MyCustomModel{total=10, description="test"});
```

Something similar can be achived using the extension method provided by MvcContrib but unfortunately for some reason the extension can't compose the correct set of parameters in the querystring ending up with an incorrect request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
TempData["MyCustomModel"] = new MyCustomModel{total=10, description="test"});
```

and then

```
MyCustomModel model = TempData["MyCustomModel"] as MyCustomModel
```

in the action method that's getting redirected to.